# How can I run dart2js dynamically in a Dart server web app?

Tags: dart

I want to compile dart code to JS on-the-fly without invoking dart2js at the command line. Eg., (written in Dart) read in some dart code from a file and transform it to JS (must be in memory, filesystem is not writable).

I thought maybe dart2js would effectively just be a cli over a pub package I can call manually, but I can't find any information on doing this at runtime :(

(note: I know this idea sucks and it'll be very slow; it's just for something I'm prototyping and will ultimately use dart2js normally, I just can't address that yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://try-dart-lang.appspot.com/ does this. The source is available. Its basically `dart2js` run through `dart2js`.
Not sure if this is the right repository https://github.com/peter-ahe-google/orphan-try
I guess Peter would be ok with pinging him about more information.

The project was replaced by pub.dartlang.org which uses a service running on the server https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-services where source is posted to for `dart2js` translation.

Comment: Great; I'll take a look there. I don't need to run it in JS (I want to run it in dart on the server), but I guess the API will be the same. If they can run it as JS I should certainly be able to run it from Dart :)

Comment: The current live URL is https://try.dartlang.org/. At the time of writing you can make a request from anywhere to this endpoint and get back JS: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"source\": \"void main(){print('hello');}\"}" https://dart-services.appspot.com/api/dartservices/v2/compile`